# Spliting a string by null char in C

Tags: c

I'm reading from a file and need to split a string by null char.

```
    *Buff = "ABC \0 NAME \0 1231 \0 12.32";
    Tok = strtok(Buff,'\0');
    printf("Tok %s \n", Tok);
```

This does not work, strtok can not take a null argument.

Comment: I find `*Buff =` very questionable. Please post more complete code. Also, please ask a question.

Comment: C strings are null-terminated.  Your string contains null characters in places other than the end, which means you're not working with C strings, and the `string.h` functions aren't going to be much help.  You'll need to roll your own.

Comment: I don't see any reading of files. BTW the scond argument to strtok() should be a character pointer, not an integer literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use  `strlen(the_string) + 1` to get the tokens:

Example:

```
Tok = Buff;
Tok += strlen(Tok) + 1;    // first token
Tok += strlen(Tok) + 1;    // second token
Tok += strlen(Tok) + 1;    // third token, etc.
```

The terminating condition is when `Tok >= Buff + sizeof "ABC \0 NAME \0 1231 \0 12.32"`.

Comment: @user2015858 I'd recommend to use another terminating condition: Double zero termination (a very common variant). If your code fins a token with zero length, you reached the end of the buffer and stop the tokenizing. You don't have to rely on the sizeof operation (which sometime does not bring up what youo expected) and can tell the total length of tokens at runtime by simply adding another \0 after the string termination.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `strtok`. Just keep taking `strlen` to find the length of the token and add it to your pointer + 1.

As Carl Norum points out, you need the full length of the string since a `\0` doesn't tell you where the string actually stops.

Comment: This algorithm will work fine as long as you know when to stop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason why `strtok` does not work with `'\0'` separators: you cannot solve this problem without knowing the full length of the string. Otherwise, when you discover `'\0'`, you have no idea if that's a separator or if the string has already ended. Note that `strlen` is not going to help - it would stop as soon as it discovers the first embedded `'\0'`.

Other than that "little" problem, all you need to do is discovering the beginning of tokens: they happen to be one character after the `'\0'` character that you have previously discovered.

Answer (score -1):

You need this:

```
char Buff[] = "ABC \\0 NAME \\0 1231 \\0 12.32";
char delims[] = "\0"  ;
char *result = NULL;  
result = strtok( Buff, delims );
```

Now you can simply iterate over the 'result' until you get NULL i.e. all the strings have been found!

Cheers